# Table side by side cannot run

Tags: tables

I want to try to put the table side by side. I follow a tutorial on the internet, but I cannot run. I still waiting for the compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
        \begin{subtable}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}
            \hline
            \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Notes} \\
            \hline
            h & 10668 & m & Altitude\\
            $\rho$ & 0.379 & $\text{kg/m}^3$ & Air density \\
            Ma & 0.90 & & Mach number\\
            $\theta = 0$ & 2.86 & deg & Initial attitude \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Flight conditions}
        \end{subtable}
        \hfill
        \begin{subtable}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}}
            \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Notes} \\
            \hline
            A & 18.22 & $m^2$ & Wing area\\
            b & 0.379 & m  & Wing span \\
            c & 2.91 & m & Wing mean chord \\
            AR & 2.45 &  & Aspect ratio \\
            e & 0.92 & & Oswald factor \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Geometric data}
         \end{subtable}
    \end{table}

    \newpage 

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where are defined `subtable`?

Comment: To use `\text{}` in maths you need the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself which is most likely a missing package, I'd suggest taking a look at the siunitx package to improve the units.

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE gives errors because:

- you not load `subcaption` package
- the column specification at the second table has one `}` to much

beside this your tables are too wide, so they overlaps.

You may liked the following redesign of your table

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
          \hline
          \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}}   & \textbf{Notes}   \\
          \hline
          h               & \SI{10668}{m}      & Altitude         \\
          $\rho$          & \SI{0.379}{kg/m^3} & Air density      \\
          Ma              & 0.90               & Mach number      \\
          $\theta = 0$    & \SI{2.86}{\degree} & Initial attitude \\
          \hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \caption{Flight conditions}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
          \hline
          \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}} & \textbf{Notes}  \\
          \hline
          A               & \SI{18.22}{m^2}  & Wing area       \\
          b               & \SI{0.379}{m}    & Wing span       \\
          c               & \SI{2.91}{m}     & Wing mean chord \\
          AR              & 2.45             & Aspect ratio    \\
          e               & 0.92             & Oswald factor   \\
          \hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \caption{Geometric data}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we apply same solution to two-column papers?

Comment: @alper, yes, you can. Due to table width iz should span across bot columns, so instead of `figure` you should use `figure*`. However, be aware that iz will appear on the top of the next page from point of inserting in document. For more details about solution for the your problem, please ask new question where provide an example of your document.

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653864/how-can-i-use-subtable-as-single-column-inside-twocolumn-documentclass.  On the answer `\begin{strip}` does not work as I want where if there is a long table it does not continue from the next page

Answer (score 1):

There was a spurious `}` in the second `\begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}}`, and you should use the `siunitx` package for typesetting units, and lastly you need the `amsmath` package to use `\text{}` inside a maths environment.

Changing the margins slightly I then get:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{subtable}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}
                \hline
                \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Notes} \\
                \hline
                h & 10668 & m & Altitude\\
                $\rho$ & 0.379 & $\text{kg/m}^3$ & Air density \\
                $\rho$ & 0.379 & \si{\kilogram\per \meter^3} & Air density \\
                Ma & 0.90 & & Mach number\\
                $\theta = 0$ & 2.86 & deg & Initial attitude \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Flight conditions}
        \end{subtable}
        \hfill
        \begin{subtable}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}
            \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Units} & \textbf{Notes} \\
            \hline
            A & 18.22 & \si{\meter^2} & Wing area\\
            b & 0.379 & m  & Wing span \\
            c & 2.91 & m & Wing mean chord \\
            AR & 2.45 &  & Aspect ratio \\
            e & 0.92 & & Oswald factor \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Geometric data}
    \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\newpage 

\end{document}
```